# How I can merge three rasters with sum cell

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst

I am working by ArcGIS 10 and I have three raster 
all of raster have value cell 
and I want output raster have the sum of pixels values

Answer (score 7):

One method is to use [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) to combine your three input rasters:

[image: Raster calculator]

However, Raster Calculator doesn't do a great job of handling NoData cells. For this, you are better off using the [Cell Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm) tool:

[image]

Comment: but I saw sell value 1 + 0 + nodata = nodata it doesn't I want I want  1 + 0 + nodata = 1 I think that is sum

Comment: @HishamDarwishAzzam You can use the `ignore_nodata` parameter of the Cell Statistics tool to control the behavior of NoData values.